# Interaction between line of sight, enemy reach and opportunity attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, opportunity-attack, line-of-sight

The basic rules state for opportunity attacks:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

RAW seems to imply that by circling around the enemy before leaving his reach oppportunity attacks are completely prevented. That would mean that in most situations for medium sized enemies, characters could easily leave the reach of them without using the disengage action or provoking opportunity attacks - am I wrong?

Comment: *"characters could easily leave the reach of them without using the disengage action or provoking opportunity attacks"* — how exactly?

Comment: Yikes, I guess the "you can see" part is there to make sure unseen enemies don't get OAd. Makes a lot more sense that way

Comment: In 5e "unseen" means invisible, hidden enemies, or enemies behind total  cover.